# floating left side button for call me and contact me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a floating left side, out of the main container, for call me and contact me. 
similar to this http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Floating-Social-Share-Contact-Sidebar/

the contact button opens your email client but I'd like it to pop open a form to fill out instead.
this is an [example](http://nobetterview.com) of what I've used before from contactme.com but they are shutting down. I know the html code to make the call me button work

Basically, I want to know how to be able to code something like that.

Comment: look into responsive frameworks like foundation and bootstrap they have good modals you can use.. but first of all TRY something then come back :)

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: I basically am looking to make a code similar to what is in my example since contactme is shutting down. Also, contactme adds their logo at the bottom and I don't want that.

Comment: Please update your post with the code snippet that you have tried.

Comment: it's below in my comment

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that I currently have

```
<script type="text/javascript">var _cmo = {form: '55cd1ee8adfbd40003002d54', text: 'Contact', align: 'left', valign: 'middle', lang: 'en', background_color: '#003E02'}; (function() {var cms = document.createElement('script'); cms.type = 'text/javascript'; cms.async = true; cms.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d1uwd25yvxu96k.cloudfront.net' : 'http://static.contactme.com') + '/widgets/tab/v1/tab.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(cms, s);})();</script>
```

Comment: please click on this link and notice how the button stays on the left in the middle when you scroll down http://nobetterview.com/index.html